# How to find the power of generator defined over finite field , $\mathbb F_{2 ^m}$?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, finite-fields, coding-theory

[image]

1. List item[image]

Actually ,I am trying to execute the algorithm to find the power of generator of field(group) as shown in table of attached file but when k=7 and onward ,I could not understand what is going on.so please explain the logic.

Comment: I use the same polynomial in the third section of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) I designed with referrals like this in mind. The difference is that I used $\gamma$ instead of $u$. Scroll down that answer to get to the part with a lot of $\gamma$s :-) The idea is that whenever the multiplication forces $\gamma^4$ (or $u^4$) to appear, you replace it with $\gamma+1$ (or $u+1$), and continue.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Thank you very much,now I got the exact logic what I wanted.

Comment: Please put that as an answer: since this question shows up in the list of unanswered questions.